# Flickering loading states in useInfiniteQuery from TanStack Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm using TanStack Query v4 to render a table which also works as an infinite list in a react app.
The issue is that when the user has scrolled into the infinite list, if he chooses to add a filter, react query handles the api calls by sequentially calling all the "pages" that currently make up the list, which is what I expect, however, it does that while flickering the loading states between true and false.

So if I had multiple pages of an infinite list, if a refetch were to happen, it seems to first set isRefetching to true, and then set it to false while setting isFetchingNextPage to true.
Then after that page is fetched, it sets it to false, but then if there are more pages to fetch, it would then set it to true again and repeat the process untill there were no more pages to fetch.
It seems sane and correct that it works like that, but I'm struggling to find a way to derive a boolean from the provided variables that would actually indicate the full loading experience to the user.

As of now, if I render my loading property like this:
`loading={isLoading || isFetchingNextPage || isRefetching}`
What happens is that the loading indicator flickers during the process, because isRefetching seems to only be true for the first api call, then isFetchingNextPage swaps between true and false multiple times until all pages are loaded.

I want the render a loading indicator that would be true from the moment the isRefetching variable switched to true all the way until the final isFetchingNextPage switched to false. How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance for any help!